# circular reference injecting security service into voter service

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to inject ServiceA(used to fetch entities based on is_granted) into ServiceB (a voter) and getting a circular reference.

I believe because when ServiceA is loaded its authentication_checker dependency tries to load all the voters, which includes ServiceB, which requires ServiceA... etc.

Anyway to work around this?

YAML service mapping:

```
services:
app.security_service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\appSecurityService
    arguments: [ "@logger", "@doctrine", "@security.authorization_checker", "@security.token_storage" ]
app.entity_voter:
    class: AppBundle\Security\ChargebackNotificationVoter
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: security.voter }
    arguments: [ "@logger", "@doctrine", "@app.security_service" ]
```

An example of what I'm doing in ServiceA

```
   public function getEntitiesForUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

    if($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_SYSTEM_ADMIN')){
        //If the user has ROLE_SYSTEM_ADMIN get all the entities
        $entitiess = $this->managerRegistry->getRepository('AppBundle:Entities')->findAll();
    }elseif($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ORGANIZATION_ADMIN')){
        //ElseIf the user has ROLE_ORGANIZATION_ADMIN get all the entitiess that belong to the organization
        $entitiess = $user->getOrganization()->getEntities();
    } elseif($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        $entitiess = $this->managerRegistry->getRepository('AppBundle:Entities')->findByUser($user);
    } else {
        //if ROLE_USER is missing return null
        $entitiess = null;
    }

    return $entities;
}
```

..and the error I get

> Circular reference detected for service "security.authorization_checker", path: "twig.controller.exception -> twig -> security.authorization_checker -> security.access.decision_manager -> ccp.chargebacknotification_voter -> ccp.security_service".

Comment: I wonder if I could solve by using getRoles from the user object in ServiceA, and in_array or ->contains to check for the role, then I wouldnt need the security.auth_checker... best practice docs say use the security.auth_checker to check roles though :/

Comment: Which Symfony version do you use?

Comment: symfony3, I asked in the IRC channel as well and it sounds like as long as the service has a dependancy on the security.authentication_checker, it cannot be injected into the voter. My current workaround is adding a hasRole method on the user object, and using that to check roles in my service which allows me to remove the security.auth_checker dependancy and inject it into my voter without any problems

Answer (score 1):

You can try to inject `security.authorization_checker` (resp. `app.security_service`) into `app.security_service` (resp. `app.entity_voter`) using setter method:

```
services:
app.security_service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\appSecurityService
    arguments: [ "@logger", "@doctrine", "@security.token_storage" ]
    calls:
            - [setAuthorizationChecker, ['@security.authorization_checker']]
app.entity_voter:
    class: AppBundle\Security\ChargebackNotificationVoter
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: security.voter }
    arguments: [ "@logger", "@doctrine" ]
    calls:
            - [setSecurityService, ['@app.security_service']]
```

I use Symfony3